# sf equivalent of R maptools package's SpatialLinesMidPoints

Tags: r, sp, sf, maptools

I've been moving most of my workflow to using the sf package in R, and I'm trying to find the equivalent to the maptools package SpatialLinesMidPoints function - I've used this function frequently over the years and had modified to get line endpoints as well ([here](https://gist.github.com/mhweber/d0e16ae9ff9beee798ea)).

Is there an equivalent function using sf package?  I've looked at st_cast and st_line_sample, but want to explicitly get midpoints of lines. I'm guessing perhaps I can make use of either st_cast or st_line_sample with slight modification to get just midpoints but struggling a bit with approach.

Just to be explicit, I'm looking for equivalent of doing:

```
library(spData)
library(maptools)
library(sf)

seine <- as(seine, 'Spatial')
seine_midpoints <- SpatialLinesMidPoints(seine)
# To verify:
plot(seine, axes=T)
plot(seine_midpoints, add=T, col='red')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like maptools:::getMidpoint, which underpins maptools::SpatialLinesMidPoints, can be applied to a LINESTRING geometry set without too much modification, e.g.

```
st_line_midpoints <- function(sf_lines = NULL) {

  g <- st_geometry(sf_lines)

  g_mids <- lapply(g, function(x) {

    coords <- as.matrix(x)

    # this is just a copypaste of View(maptools:::getMidpoints):
    get_mids <- function (coords) {
      dist <- sqrt((diff(coords[, 1])^2 + (diff(coords[, 2]))^2))
      dist_mid <- sum(dist)/2
      dist_cum <- c(0, cumsum(dist))
      end_index <- which(dist_cum > dist_mid)[1]
      start_index <- end_index - 1
      start <- coords[start_index, ]
      end <- coords[end_index, ]
      dist_remaining <- dist_mid - dist_cum[start_index]
      mid <- start + (end - start) * (dist_remaining/dist[start_index])
      return(mid)
    }

    mids <- st_point(get_mids(coords))
    })

  out <- st_sfc(g_mids, crs = st_crs(sf_lines))
  out <- st_sf(out)
}
```

So,

```
seine_sf <- st_as_sf(seine)
seine_sf_mids <- st_line_midpoints(seine_sf)

plot(seine_sf)
plot(seine_sf_mids, add = TRUE)
```

Looks ok for sfc_LINESTRING, but the function would need some tweaks to handle sfc_MULTILINESTRING.

Comment: @mweber, if this worked please accept the answer so it will be closed. There are too many open answers on this site that have valid solutions presented.

Comment: st_line_sample(x, n=1) or st_line_sample(x, sample=0.5)
st_centroid would also work in the special case of a straight line segment